# Composition of substitutions for unary addition in prolog?

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

Can someone explain how the logic of the composition of substitutions works with the following block of code?

```
plus2(0, X, X).          % 0+X = X
plus2(s(X), Y, s(Z)) :-
    plus2(Y, X, Z).      % (X+1) + Y = Z+1  therefore  Y+X=Z
```

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be plus2 just updated the code, and I don't think swapping X and Y changes the logic here.

Comment: "*I don't think swapping X and Y changes the logic here.*" - It doesn't change the logic for the computer, it changes the difficulty of explaining it for the human. In your code X+1=Z and the next step is 0+X=X, and X=1, X=0, X=1 (again), X=Y and X=Z, but they're different Xs in different parts of the call stack. If you're struggling to understand it, that isn't gonna help. Name the first line `plus2(0, YZ, YZ).` to show that the recursion stops when you've taken enough units from Z that it's down to being the same value as Y, for example.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, I can see it, but the logic here is adapted from the workbook!.

Comment: Swapping the two numbers being summed is advantageous - see my answer.

Comment: `(X+1) + Y = Z+1  therefore  Y+X=Z` when reading `=` as "must be equal". But if we read `=` is "equals" (which is more usually done) then "therefore" becomes "if". (i.e. the direction changes to the opposite!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is better naming:

```
% Reduced to zero
peano_add(0, Sum, Sum).
peano_add(s(N), M, s(Sum)) :-
    % Decrement towards 0
    % Swap N & M, because N + M is M + N
    peano_add(M, N, Sum).
```

This is using Peano arithmetic, which represents natural numbers (i.e. integers starting from zero) in a *relative* way, as compound terms, as successors ultimately of 0. For example, `s(s(0))` represents 2. Such relativity is convenient and elegant for Prolog, because it can be used ("reasoned with") in an uninstantiated ([var](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=var/1)) variable.

In swi-prolog, this produces:

```
?- peano_add(N, M, Sum).
N = 0,
M = Sum ;   % When N is zero, M is same as Sum - could be 0 or successor
N = Sum, Sum = s(_),
M = 0 ;     % When M is zero, N is same as Sum
N = s(0),
M = s(_A),
Sum = s(s(_A)) ;  % 1 + 1 = 2
N = s(s(_A)),
M = s(0),
Sum = s(s(s(_A))) ;  % 2 + 1 = 3
N = s(s(0)),
M = s(s(_A)),
Sum = s(s(s(s(_A)))) ;  % 2 + 2 = 4
N = s(s(s(_A))),
M = s(s(0)),
Sum = s(s(s(s(s(_A)))))  % 3 + 2 = 5  etc.
```

... and if we ask it how we can add two natural numbers to sum to 2:

```
?- peano_add(N, M, s(s(0))).
N = 0,
M = s(s(0)) ;      % 0 + 2
N = s(s(0)),
M = 0 ;            % 2 + 0
N = M, M = s(0) ;  % 1 + 1
false.
```

Whereas if we don't swap the arguments:

```
% Reduced to zero
peano_add(0, Sum, Sum).
peano_add(s(N), M, s(Sum)) :-
    % Decrement towards 0
    % Not swapping args, to demonstrate weakness
    peano_add(N, M, Sum).
```

... we get:

```
?- peano_add(N, M, Sum).
N = 0,
M = Sum ;
N = s(0),
Sum = s(M) ;
N = s(s(0)),
Sum = s(s(M)) ;
N = s(s(s(0))),
Sum = s(s(s(M))) ;
N = s(s(s(s(0)))),
Sum = s(s(s(s(M)))) ;
```

... which is still correct, but doesn't "involve" `M` as much as it could.

Both methods are counting from 0 upwards to infinity.

Swapping the parameters brings the advantage of checking the 2nd argument, to fail both [fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) and when appropriate:

```
?- peano_add(s(s(N)), z, Sum).
false.   % Correct, because z is not valid

% Versus, when unswapped, this undesirable:
?- peano_add(s(s(N)), z, Sum).
N = 0,
Sum = s(s(z)) ;  % Wrong - did not check whether z is valid
N = s(0),
Sum = s(s(s(z))) ;  % Still wrong
N = s(s(0)),
Sum = s(s(s(s(z)))) ;  % Will keep being wrong
```

Sadly, there is a common practice in Prolog example code of using meaningless variable names (such as A, B, X, Y), which adds confusion and should be generally avoided.

**Addendum:** Here is a version which has better determinism, when 2 of the 3 arguments are ground:

```
peano_add(P, Q, S) :-
    % For first-argument indexing
    (   ground(P)
    ->  peano_add_(P, Q, S)
    ;   peano_add_(Q, P, S)
    ).

peano_add_(0, S, S) :-
    peano(S).
peano_add_(s(P), Q, s(S)) :-
    peano_add_(P, Q, S).

peano(0).
peano(s(P)) :-
    peano(P).

peano_subtract(P, Q, S) :-
    % P - Q equals S means S + Q equals P
    peano_add(S, Q, P).
```

Comment: can you explain, % When N is zero, M is the same as Sum - could be 0 or successor, how can M be a successor?

Comment: A "successor" is `s(0)` or `s(s(0))` or `s(s(s(0)))` etc.

Comment: Now, I get the logic; the workbook should work on naming the variables; thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Composition of substitutions means that if under substitution `θ1` we have

```
A = s(B)
```

and under substitution  `θ2` we have

```
      B = s(C)
```

then under the composed substitution
`θ1 U θ2` we have

```
A = s(    s(C))
```

This can be seen e.g. in the call

```
%% the code, for reference:
plus2(0, X, X).
plus2(s(X), Y, s(Z)) :- plus2(Y, X, Z).

%% the call:
  plus2( s(1), 0, SUM )
 =plus2( s(X), Y, s(Z))     under θ1 = {1=X, 0=Y, SUM=s(Z)}
  :- plus2(  Y, X, Z)       under θ1
    =plus2(  0, 1, Z)
     :-plus2(0,X2,X2)       under θ2 = {1=X2, Z=X2}
```

Thus the composed substitution is

```
   θ = θ1 U θ2 = {1=X, 0=Y, SUM=s(Z), 1=X2, Z=X2}
```

and the original query holds under `θ` as

```
  plus2( s(1), 0, SUM  )    % under θ1, SUM=s(Z     )
 =plus2( s(1), 0, s(Z) )    % under θ2,       Z=X2
 =plus2( s(1), 0, s(X2))    % under θ2,         X2=1
 =plus2( s(1), 0, s(1) ).   % under θ,  SUM=s(     1)
```

Thus, as the proof progresses, the answer term `SUM` is progressively instantiated in the top-down manner.