# Prolog: plus in gnu prolog?

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I'm trying to write a plus expression for Prolog.

Using an example from the Art of Prolog:

```
nat(0).
nat(N) :- N > 0, M is N - 1, nat(M).
plus(X, 0, X) :- nat(X).
plus(X, s(Y), s(Z)) :- plus(X, Y, Z).
```

Then I query:

```
| ?- plus(1, 1, Y).

no
```

Why is this not `Y = 2`?

I tried the example [here in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74923153/composition-of-substitutions-for-unary-addition-in-prolog/74939598#74939598) as follows with similar results:

```
peano_add(0, Sum, Sum).
peano_add(s(N), M, s(Sum)) :- peano_add(M, N, Sum).

| ?- peano_add(1, 1, Y).

no
```

[image]

Comment: For Peano addition: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74939598/

Comment: @brebs I tried that example marked as the answer and still have problems with 1 + 1 as updated in the post.

Comment: You are mixing up Peano and numbers as if they are the same. To convert between them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75645668/

Answer (score 0):

"1" is not `1`, it is the successor of 0. Also, now the other answer is confusing this additionally since "natural" is supposed to be defined like this (isn't it like that in the book??):

```
natural(0).
natural(s(X)) :- natural(X).
```

So with this and plus/3, as defined in your example,

```
plus(0, X, X) :- natural(X).
plus(s(X), Y, s(Z)) :- plus(X, Y, Z).
```

if you wanted to add 1 and 1, since 1 is the successor of 0, you'd have to write:

```
?- plus(s(0), s(0), X).
```

And this should answer `X = s(s(0))`, since one plus one is two. You can also subtract with this predicate. Here is the whole thing on GNU-Prolog:

```
$ gprolog
GNU Prolog 1.4.5 (64 bits)
Compiled Dec 21 2020, 08:56:50 with gcc
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2020 Daniel Diaz
| ?- [user]. % define predicates
compiling user for byte code...
natural(0).
natural(s(X)) :- natural(X).
plus(0, X, X) :- natural(X).
plus(s(X), Y, s(Z)) :- plus(X, Y, Z).
end_of_file.
user compiled, 5 lines read - 673 bytes written, 17939 ms

(1 ms) yes
| ?- plus(s(0), s(0), X). % add 1 + 1

X = s(s(0))

yes
| ?- plus(s(0), X, s(s(s(s(0))))). % subtract 4 - 1

X = s(s(s(0)))

yes
```